# Move last character of every item in list to the start of the next item

Tags: python

Is there any way to move every last character of every item of a list to the start of the next item?

For example

```
['HelloM','yN','ameI','sB','ob']
```

would turn into

```
['Hello','My','Name','Is','Bob']
```

Comment: There is, but you have to implement it, there's no built-in function.

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to do it by looping:

```
l=['HelloM','yN','ameI','sB','ob']
for e in range(len(l)-1):
    l[e+1]=l[e][-1]+l[e+1]
    l[e]=l[e][:-1]
```

Comment: Legend. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in range(len(li)):
    if i!= len(li) - 1:
       li[i + 1] = li[i][-1] + li[i + 1]
       li[i] = li[i][:-1]
```

Comment: Nice looking code, but could probably do with a bit of an explanation.